# Give a variable as ID to a div - Correct Syntax

Tags: php

I have some problems assigning a php variable as an ID to a div.
My code is currently like this

```
echo "<div>";
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
echo "$content"; 
echo "</div>";
```

If i wanted to assign a variable, say $hello as id to this div, how should i do? Obviously, the html result should be `<div id="hellovariablecontent">`, but i can't come up with a valid solution even after looking several times at the php special character syntax. Any help would be super-appreciated!

Comment: you need to learn Concatenate Strings . 
http://phphowto.blogspot.in/2006/12/concatenate-strings.html 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do exactly what you are attempting, though if you are using single quotes instead of double, the variable will not be parsed.

Another option would be

```
echo "<div id=" . $hello . ">";
echo "<h3>" . $title . "</h3>";
echo $content; 
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! In the end i went with 
    echo "<h3>" . $title . "</h3>"; 
and it worked perfectly, just as you said.
@Sunil Silumala Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div id="<?php echo $title ?>" >
 <?php echo $content ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I've understand your question, but I guess you meant sometimes like that:

```
echo '<div id="'. $id .'">';
```

If you really want to use double quote signs, you might escape them, if you need to output them inside the string. Like:

```
echo "<div id=\"$id\">";
```

But I really recommend you to use the first and to get familiar with that. It's way better to read inside your code as you can identify values without a closer look - so it's easier to debug for you and others that might read your code in further time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes like this `' id= "'.$hello.'" '`, I should mention that `.` is used as concatenator for strings because variables are not being parsed within single quotes.

Or escape the double quotes with `\`.

Here's both examples.

Single quotes:

```
echo '<div id="'.$hello.'" >';
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
echo "$content"; 
echo "</div>";
```

Double quotes:

```
echo "<div id=\"$hello\" >";
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
echo "$content"; 
echo "</div>";
```